# Using sphinx WebSupport: Is it possible to disable commenting for specific content?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm using the [Sphinx API](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/websupport.html) to integrate Sphinx documentation into a web application.

I want the users to be able to contribute to the documentation, so I use the comments/voting framework built in to Sphinx WebSupport.

In most cases, this works great: Each paragraph of the documentation can be commented.

A couple of places in the documentation, I use tables. Sphinx creates comment icons for each cell in the table. Is there a way to disable the comment icons inside tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by modifying `websupport.js`.

In the `$(document).ready` event handler, change:

```
$('.sphinx-has-comment').comment();
```

to:

```
$('.sphinx-has-comment:not(table p)').comment();
```